# Passing uibutton tag through UILongPressGestureRecognizer?

Tags: swift, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am trying to use the long press button function but am not sure how to pass the tag of the button to the function. I have an array of buttons called ChannelButton. The long button press works with the code below.

```
for button in ChannelButton {
        let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(sender:)))
        button.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
    }
func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        doSomeFunction(NeedToPassTheButtonsTagHere)
}
```

But I need it to modify it to be something like this

```
for button in ChannelButton {
        let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(sender:, button.tag)))
        button.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
    }


    func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer, buttontag) {
        doSomeFunction(buttontag)
}
```

I know this doesn't work but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

A `UIGestureRecognizer` has a `view` property that is the `view` that it is attached to.  In your case, it will be your button.  Use it to get to your button's `tag`:

```
func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let button = sender.view as? UIButton else { return }

    doSomeFunction(button.tag)
}
```

Comment: When I did that, It gave me the yellow warning. . .
"Result of call to 'makeSoloRequest' is unused"

        func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let button = sender.view as? UIButton else { return }
        makeSoloRequest(button.tag)
    }

Comment: What is your makeSoloRequest doing?

Comment: func makeSoloRequest(_ inputNumber: Int) -> NSMutableURLRequest
    {
        print("Solo Request!!!")
        return NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(baserequest)Solo&Input=\(inputNumber)" )!)

    }

Comment: That function is returning a NSMutableURLRequest, so make sure to point a variable to that function when calling it, for example    let url = makeSoloRequest(someInt)

Comment: .. or to ignore the result `_ = makeSoloRequest(button.tag)`

Comment: @SethHaberman, did this solve your issue of accessing the button tag in your `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` handler?

Comment: Yes! I think this is the code that worked

    func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let button = sender.view as? UIButton else { return }if sender.state == 
    UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
}

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add an EXTRA parameter (an int) to an IBAction selector. You can't do that. IBActions have one of 3 selectors:

```
@IBAction func actionNoParams() {
}

@IBAction func actionWSender(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func actionWSenderAndEvent(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
}
```

One solution would be to look for the location of your long press gesture, and then check what button has that location.

```
func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

        let location = sender.location(in: self.view)

        for button in ChannelButton {

            if button.frame.contains(location) {

                //This is the button that is pressed
                //Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate